# GCCARM .s file error

Tags: gcc, arm

I am getting error on this line `GCC ARM boot.s file`

```
.IF (:LNOT:(:DEF:NO_CLOCK_SETUP)):LAND:(CLOCK_SETUP != 0)
```

how to solve this ?

Comment: And the error says...

Comment: boot.s:1101: Error: bad expression
boot.s:1101: Error: missing ')'
boot.s:1101: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `L'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line contains assembler operators for the ARM assembler that the GNU assembler, `gas`, doesn't understand:

- [ARM assembler Unary Operators](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Cacdcihg.html)
- [ARM assembler Binary Operators](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Cacdfcge.html)

You'll either need to build with the ARM assembler or modify the `boot.s` file to use syntax that the GNU assembler will understand.

Comment: so what i need to change in this line, i am just started with ARM.

Comment: @Ramoliya.Biren: I don't know enough about your project to do much more than guess.

Comment: so will send my boot.s file.